# How to access local static variables and local variables inside a function from other files in C/C++ programming?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, static, external

```
file1.c

int b=2;

void func(){
    int c=10;
    static int d=10;
    int *cp=&c;
}

main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern b;
extern *cp;

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    printf("a=%d\nb=%d\n",a,b);
    printf("c=%d\nd=%d\n",c,*cp);
    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't able to access local variable 'c' from other file using pointe '*cp' as well.
I know by default we can access the functions from other files without using extern keyword but how to access the local variables and static variables present inside those functions ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The variables in that function are scoped for use only in that function. However if you made variable `c` a static one, you could make a global pointer, declared in the same place as `b`. Then you could declare a `extern int *ptr_to_c` in `main.c` and be able to access the variable `c` through pointer access.

Comment: So we can't able to access d in file1.c even though it was a static variable ? and I am getting 'c undeclared" though I've made *cp as a global pointer pointing to c

Comment: No. You can;t access `d` in file1.c because it is not global. It is a local variable. Static means for variables to retain values between calls. It will exist till the end of the program. 'static` for function means visible only in this file.

Answer (score 0):

````
```c
file1.c

int b=2;

void func(){
// local scope, stored ok stack, can only be accessed in this function
    int c=10;
// stored in RAM, can only be accessed in this function
// but if you take a pointer to it, it will be valid after this function executes
    static int d=10;
// the pointer itself, cp is stored on stack and has local scope
    int *cp=&c;
}

main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// this will allow you to access "b" in file1.c
// it should read: extern int b;
extern b;
// you will probably get link errors, this does not exist
extern *cp;

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    printf("a=%d\nb=%d\n",a,b);
    printf("c=%d\nd=%d\n",c,*cp);
    return 0;
}
```
````

You could do this:

file1.cpp

```c
int * cp =0;
void func() {
  static int c;
  // store c's adress in cp
  cp = &c;
}
```

main.c

```c
extern int *cp;
int main()
{
 // you need to call this otherwise cp is null
  func();
  *cp = 5;
}
```

However, this is very bad c code. You should simply declare int c with file scope in file1.c exactly like b.

In practice, if you think you need `static` variables inside a function you should stop and reconsider.

Comment: Consider revising so the address is obtained through an `int **` parameter of the function instead of a global

Comment: I agree it would be a better solution but what's the point of introducing '**' to someone who is struggling with scopes and simple pointers ?